# How to change a value in AngularJS based on route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to change the href link of this "next" arrow in my application based on the route I am on. The application is a slideshow and the next arrow should take you through all the routes. What's the best way to do this?

**So for example**, if I am on the '/' route the next arrow should take me to '/overall-results' and if I am on '/overall-results' the next arrow should take me to '/swim-lane'. I know the easiest thing to do it make this "arrow" on each page and have a different link for it, but if there's an angular way to this I would like to know.

Route file:

```
angular
.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
        controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/overall-results', {
        templateUrl: 'views/overall.html',
        controller: 'overallCtrl'
      })
  .when('/swim-lane-results', {
    templateUrl: 'views/swim-lane.html',
    controller: 'swimlaneCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Where my navigation arrow is:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
<a href="#/{{nextlink}}">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a controller for each route, you can keep the template the same, and reference a $rootScope that changes on each controller.

```
<!-- welcomeCtrl -->
$rootScope.nextLink = "overall-results";

<!-- overallCtrl -->
$rootScope.nextLink = "swim-lane-results";

<!-- swimlaneCtrl -->
$rootScope.nextLink = "somethingelse";

<!-- navigation template shared by all controllers/templates -->
<a ng-href="/{{nextLink}}">Next Link</a>
```

Comment: How would I link this ng-href element to all the controllers? The next arrow is outside my ng-view

Comment: The scope outside the ng-view is the $rootScope. By changing the $rootScope.nextLink variable you are changing the href of the next arrow.

Comment: It's valid to point out that you should avoid exposing a bunch of global variables on `$rootScope`. It's a much better practice to share data between a service.

Comment: @Dan so in all my controllers (overallCtrl, swimLaneCtrl, etc) I should have a $rootscope nextLink?